# Windows Phone 7 throws EndpointNotFoundException after one minute

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, timeout, endpoint

Calling a WCF Service in my application throws EndpointNotFoundException after one minute. All timeouts are more than one minute.

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding {
    OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3),
    CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(6),
    ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
    SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
};
client = new ServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://..."));
client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4);
```

I found a thread on Microsoft's forum, but there is no solution.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/windowsphone7series/thread/cba9c633-6d79-4c04-8c08-cd0b5b33d8c6

The problem occurs only with services that work out more than one minute. 
Invoke of this service throws EndpointNotFoundException:

```
public string Test() {
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
    return "test";
}
```

But invoke of this service works correctly:

```
public string Test() {
    Thread.Sleep(58000);
    return "test";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded .NET Framework's libraries from Windows Phone device and decompile they.

HttpWebRequest has unchangeable timeout in 1 minute.

To confirm, I created an aspx page. If I put Thread.Sleep(60000) in Page_Load, HttpWebRequest will not be able to get an response.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question if the problem occures on the emulator or the device.
If it is occuring on the emulator do you have network access - i.e. can you see external sites from IE. If not check the proxy settings on your host machine as a LAN proxy will prevent the emulator communicating.

Comment: There is access to the network. The problem occurs only with services that work out more than one minute.
On the PC service is called correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What are the server-side timeouts set to?  Sounds like the issue may possibly be at the other end of the wire.

Comment: Yes, it's set to 5-10 minutes.
On the PC service is called correctly. So the problem is likely at some particulars of Windows Phone, no on the side of the service.